# Using adverbs or adjectives before "present participle adjectives"

Tags: meaning, adjective-phrases

I am not sure about the difference between using "ly-formed adverbs" and using "sole adjectives" before "present participle adjectives".

I think in the first sentence "relentless"   qualify "beating heat" , in the second sentence "relentlessly" qualify the "beating" ?

> 1-The ***relentless beating*** heat was beginning to confuse me. (sole
>   adjective)
>
> 2-The ***relentlessly beating*** heat was beginning to confuse me.
>   (ly-formed adverb)

Comment: Preliminary point: "beating" is best analysed as a verb, not an adjective. Other than that, you have it right.

Comment: "Beating" is not an adjective because it can't be modified by "very", and it can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" (*"It became/seemed quite beating") or complex-transitive verbs like "find" (*"I found it quite beating"). "Beating" has none of the properties of  indisputable adjectives and hence can't belong in that class. Other examples of verbs modifying nouns include "a sleeping child", "the gleaming showroom".